# jQuery Button Click 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say we have a simple event button handler:

```
$( "#aButton" ).click(function() {
   console.log( "tile" + this.val() + "clicked" );
});
```

I realize that "this" is most contexts would refer to the "window" object.....but everywhere i've been looking at code examples of "this" talks about Jquery being a special case, where `this` is implied to be whatever object the event handler was on (Which i've always thought `this` was based on whatever "called" the function, and the "Window" is what called the function?

If this simply isn't true for jQuery, is there a better way around referring to the object that was clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to obtain the clicked element.

```
$("#aButton").click(function() {
    console.log("tile " + $(this).val() + " clicked");
});
```

In addition, you can note that `$(this)[0] === this`

`this` should can be used when using built in JavaScript methods, such as `.addEventListener()`. Using `this` in this context will return the Node that triggered the event.

Comment: If I used normal JS methods of checking for .click/etc... would `this` suffice or would it also need to be wrapped?

Comment: You can use `this.value`

Comment: Yes, you can use `this` when using the normal `.addEventListener()` function and it will return the Node that calls the event.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the raw DOM element. You have to wrap it in a jQuery object if you want to use jQuery functions on it.

```
console.log( "tile" + $(this).val() + "clicked" );
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Inputs have a property called `value` that does the same. So you can use it on raw DOM inputs like this:

```
console.log( "tile" + this.value + "clicked" );
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The object that you clicked can be referred by `this`, so saying `this.id` will give you button's id "aButton". However, if you want to use jQuery's methods then you have to say `$(this).attr('id')` which will again give you "aButton".
So you do have different mechanisms available to you but if you are using jQuery, it is preferable to use jQuery methods.